# In python I cannot get the right product

Tags: python, list

```
my_list = ["banana", "apple", "cherry"]

var = my_list.remove("apple")

print(var)
```

When I run this it is suppose to write

```
apple
```

p.s I am new to coding

Comment: `list.remove()` does not return the removed element - why would it need to, since you already know which element it removed? You could use `var = my_list.pop(my_list.index("apple"))`, but that's extra steps.

Comment: Why did you expect `remove()` to return the removed element?

Answer (score 0):

In python, remove method for list does not return anything. It will throw an exception if the element does not exist. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pop instead. You have to specify the index you are removing from.

```
my_list = ["banana", "apple", "cherry"]

var = my_list.pop(my_list.index("apple"))

print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons I always recommend using an IDE when programming in Python.  PyCharm gives you the warning "remove doesn't return a value".

Answer (score 0):

You can get element from list by slicing or [pop()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html%27) item from list

```
my_list = ["banana", "apple", "cherry"]
print(my_list[my_list.index('apple')])
#apple
print(my_list.pop(my_list.index('apple')))
#apple
```